# Quarkus - How to test reactive flow for onFailure()

Tags: java, quarkus, quarkus-panache, quarkus-rest-client

I have reactive quarkus resource where I am using Mongo Reactive Panache. I have a logic that if the emailId of person exist then code should throw BusinessException.

I am able to test the happy path but how do I trigger negative test. Here's my code and test class.

**PersonResource.java**

```
@POST
    public Uni<Response> create(Person person){
        return repository.persist(person). map(r ->
                Response.ok(r).build())
                .onFailure()
                .recoverWithItem(f-> {
                    AStatus status =  createErrorStatus(f.getMessage());
                    return Response.serverError().entity(status).build();
                }) ;
    }
```

**PersonRepositoryTest.java**

```
package com.eventu.resource;

import com.eventu.exception.BusinessException;
import com.eventu.repository.PersonRepository;
import com.eventu.vo.Address;
import com.eventu.vo.Person;
import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;
import io.quarkus.test.junit.mockito.InjectMock;
import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni;
import io.smallrye.mutiny.helpers.test.UniAssertSubscriber;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;


@QuarkusTest
class PersonResourceTest {

     @InjectMock
    PersonRepository repository;
    @Inject
    PersonResource resource;
    Uni<Person> uniPerson;
    Person person;
    @BeforeEach
    public  void setUp(){
        person =  Person.builder().address(Address.builder()
                        .addressLine_1("1000 Test dr")
                        .addressLine_2("opposite crescent dr").suiteNumber("Ste. 200").city("testCity")
                        .countryCode("US").state("CA")
                        .build()).emailAddress("test@test.com").firstName("John").lastName("Barista")
                .mobileNumber("70444444444")

                .id(new ObjectId())
                .build();
       uniPerson = Uni.createFrom().item(person);

        when(repository.persist(any(Person.class))).thenReturn(uniPerson);
        
    }
   // THIS TEST IS WORKING 
    @Test
    @DisplayName("When a new person object is passed then person object with Id should be returned")
    void create_success() {
        final Uni<Response> p = resource.create(person);
        Person respPerson = (Person) p.subscribe().withSubscriber(UniAssertSubscriber.create()).assertCompleted().getItem().getEntity();
        Assertions.assertNotNull(p);
        Assertions.assertEquals(person, respPerson);
    }

   

    /**
     * THIS ONE FAILS WITH at line 63 with the message
     * org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
     * Checked exception is invalid for this method!
     * Invalid: com.eventu.exception.BusinessException
     */
    @Test
    @DisplayName("When a new person object is passed but email exists then AStatus object with error description")
    void create_duplicate_emailId() {
        when(repository.persist(any(Person.class))).thenThrow(BusinessException.class); /// **FAILS HERE. Tried replacing with RunTimeException.class as well** 
        final Uni<Response> p = resource.create(person);
        Person respPerson = (Person) p.subscribe().withSubscriber(UniAssertSubscriber.create()).assertCompleted().getItem().getEntity();
        //**SHOULD FAIL HERE as I EXPECT AStatus.java object**
        Assertions.assertEquals(person, respPerson);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution after trying an error. The documentation on Mutiny/Quarkus leaves a lot to be desired.
This is what's needed -

```
@Test
    @DisplayName("When a new person object is passed but email exists then AStatus object with error description")
    void create_duplicate_emailId() {
        when(repository.persist(any(Person.class)))
.thenReturn(Uni.createFrom().failure(new MongoException(11000, "Email does not exist")));
        final Uni<Response> p = resource.create(person);
        Person respPerson = (Person) p.subscribe().withSubscriber(UniAssertSubscriber.create()).assertCompleted().getItem().getEntity();
        
       .....
    }
```